# Horizontal bar notation for isomorphisms or bijections

Tags: notation

I have seen in many books, particularly on category theory, the use of an horizontal bar to indicate some sort of equivalence, but I have not seen a proper definition in any context.

For example:

$X \to Y^T$

`_________`

$T \times X \to Y$

(Excuse me for the bad formatting.)

The explanation given in the book is that a map $X \to Y^T$ *is the same as* a map  $T \times X \to Y$. What kind of sameness is this? Is there a bijection between the two collections of maps, an isomorphism, a unique isomorphism? Or does the meaning depend on the context, and it's a generic notation for equivalence?

Thanks.

I should add: I understand the intuitive meaning, but I've seen proofs using only chains of these equivalences (for example, to prove that $Y^{T+S}\cong Y^T\times Y^S$), but I'm not entirely sure of their rigor.

Comment: These proofs are rigorous. The equivalence of these statements are proved using the universal property. In the case of map objects, the universality of the map object says that if you have $T\times X\to Y$ you get $X\to Y^T$. If you start with $X\to Y^T$, the evaluation map that comes with $Y^T$ gives you the map from $T\times X\to Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User69810 has given a good explanation of the informal intent of the notation, "informal" in the sense that it refers to "doing" things and to "equivalence" between such doings.  For a formal explanation, I would say that the notation means two or even three things.  First, it means that there is a bijection between entities of the sort indicated above the line and entities of the sort indicated below.  Second, it indicates that the author has a particular such bijection in mind, and that either the reader is supposed to guess (correctly) which bijection this is or the author will explain, preferably in the next few lines of text.  Finally, if you're willing to include some category-theoretic ideas, it means that the bijection is natural.  (More details about this naturality: In most cases, including the one in your question, the entities above and below the horizontal line are not merely sets but functors of the relevant variables.  In your case, you have functors covariant in $Y$ and contravariant in $X$ and $T$.  The notation is usually understood to mean that the intended bijections, one for each choice of $Y,X,T$, constitute a natural isomorphism between these functors.)

Answer (score 1):

It means the same as in to do one is equivalent to doing the other. In your particular example, it says that in a category with map objects, specifying a map $X\to Y^T$ is exactly the same thing as specifying a map $T\times X\to Y$.

You see the same thing with products. Specifying a pair of maps $Z\to X$, $Z\to Y$ is the same thing as specifying a map $Z\to X\times Y$.

Comment: +1, but it might be worth sticking just to sets, since nothing in the OP's post indicates understanding of categories. The category sense is the deeper reason, of course...